# Rake task for pushing local file to GitHub

Tags: git, rake, rake-task

I have a `yml` file in my local project, stored in `config/locales/en.yml`.

I want to create rake task to push this file to GitHub, overwriting the existing file.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
# in lib/tasks/github.rake

namespace :github do
    desc "Push locale stored in `config/locales/en.yml` to github"
    task :push_locale do |t|
        sh "git add config/locales/en.yml"
        sh "git commit -m 'Update locale.'"
        sh "git push"
    end
end
```

and then invoke the task with `rake github:push_locale`